# how to append existing url parameters in html submit form with php?

Tags: php, html, forms, url, parameters

this doesn't work . Old parameters are lost . I get http://x.x.x.x/temp/test.php?mode=compound

```
<form align="right" action="http://<? echo $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']."/temp/test.php?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];?>">
<? if ($_SESSION['mode']=="simple") { ?>
<input type="submit" value="Switch to compound mode">
<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="compound">
<? } else { ?>
<input type="submit" value="Switch to simple mode">
<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="simple">
<? } ?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally did this with this piece of code :

```
<form align="right" action="http://<?echo $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']."/temp/test.php";?>">
<? if ($_SESSION['mode']=="simple") { ?>
<input type="submit" value="Switch to compound mode">
<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="compound">
<? } else { ?>
<input type="submit" value="Switch to simple mode">
<input type="hidden" name="mode" value="simple"> <? } 
foreach ($_GET as $id=>$parameter) { if ($id=="mode") { continue;}?>
<input type="hidden" name="<?echo $id;?>" value="<?echo $parameter;?>" /> <? } ?>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using GET parameters you could try to use

```
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']."/temp/test.php?".implode('&', $_GET);
```

in stead of

```
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']."/temp/test.php?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```